# How to limit the length of title for related products in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce, product

I am using the below code that Automatically shortens WooCommerce product titles on the static home page main shop, category, and tag pages. I want to do also that for related products. what conditional tag should i add for related product here

This code automatically shortens WooCommerce product titles on the static home page main shop, category, and tag pages to a set number of characters

```php
function short_woocommerce_product_titles_chars( $title, $id ) {
    if ( ( is_front_page() || is_shop() || is_product_tag() || is_product_category() ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
        // Kicks in if the product title is longer than 60 characters 
        if ( strlen( $title ) > 60) {
            // Shortens it to 60 characters and adds ellipsis at the end
            return substr( $title, 0, 60 ) . '...';
        }
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'short_woocommerce_product_titles_chars', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will extend your current code to related product too:

```php
function shorten_woocommerce_loop_product_titles( $title, $id ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    if ( ( is_front_page() || is_shop() || is_product_tag() || is_product_category() || ( isset($woocommerce_loop['name'])
    && $woocommerce_loop['name'] === 'related' ) ) && get_post_type( $id ) === 'product' ) {
        $length_threshold = 60; // Here define the desired number of characters max to be displayed

        // If the product title is longer than xx characters 
        if ( strlen( $title ) > $length_threshold ) {
            // Shortens it to xx characters and adds ellipsis at the end
            return substr( $title, 0, $length_threshold ) . '...';
        }
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'shorten_woocommerce_loop_product_titles', 10, 2 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your  child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: can I set the title length based on lines that means after the first line?

Comment: @MohammadSuhail Kindly, think about it… How can I guess the length of your product titles in your shop, as it depend on the CSS settings (font-width, font-familly…), the number of displayed products by row (the width of the block where the title is displayed) and so on... You need to set the best number of characters, making many tries and looking at the result. Also, this may vary from one browser to another (and from one platform to another too). This is why we use nowadays responsive design.